# How to quickly select the boot medium like old good days?

Tags: bios, dell-latitude

I remember in the older BIOSes you could press a button like F12 to select which disk to be used for booting OS. I own a Dell Latitude 5420 and am unsure how to access such a feature. I have two drives that need to switch between them quite often. Currently, I have to to to reorder boot media in the BIOS (UEFI) each time which is relatively slow to do.

Comment: Checking Dell's support knowledge system suggests that it is necessary to hold the Fn key in order to get Function key utility. If you are able to enter UEFI, then you must be aware of this. It's been my experience with Dell computers that it's going to be fn-F12 or fn-F10. Have you tried these combos?

Comment: Dell has never used F10, that is HPs boot menu.

Comment: Those "old days" pretty much ended ~2012, i.e., a decade ago.

Comment: @HandsomeNerd, I used search terms "dell 5420 boot menu hot key" and got too many results of zero value, far too generic. If you use F12 for UEFI, then the holding of the Fn key does not apply.
Moab, I've had to configure too many different brands of computers and NEVER remember which one goes where. Too many different eras, as well, to reference ChanganAuto's comment.

Comment: @fred_dot_u I am sorry, F12 actually works and shows the options to quickly change the boot order. You may add your comment like an answer so I can mark it many thanks.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Latitude 5521 user here. It's basically the same machine as OP's 5420, but with a larger screen and more powerful CPU. F12 still works. It lets you choose between available UEFI loaders. Fast boot may interfere with it though, but it can be disabled if you don't mind ~2 sec longer boot time.

Comment: @gronostaj thanks for your comment.

Comment: @gronostaj The question was about "F12 to select which **disk** (...)". This makes sense only in BIOS where only one bootloader per drive was allowed.  With UEFI it indeed "lets you choose between available UEFI loaders" which isn't the same, hence my comment. Typically there's only one ESP regardless the amount of drives or where the multiple OSes are actually installed. It's a major distinction that too many people fail to grasp a decade after BIOS disappeared from the consumer market, no doubt helped by the insistence of some vendors to use the now wrong term BIOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today's laptops have multi-function function keys. The second function is frequently a different color and is presented as an icon, for example, a speaker increasing or decreasing waves for volume control.

Early implementation of this feature required that one hold the auxiliary key, "fn or Fn" in order to implement the second option. Inconsistently, manufacturers have been setting the second option as the first, requiring that one hold the fn key to activate a "standard" F2 or F10 feature. Typically, one can change this in the setup screen (aka BIOS or UEFI) to match one's preference.

As noted in the comments, the OP has determined that pressing the function key alone without fn provides the necessary action.

Different manufacturers apply varying keys to the boot selection. I have seen Esc, F2, F10 and F12 used for this purpose.

As noted in the comments, F12 is the answer to this specific laptop.

Comment: IIRC this setting only kicks in after boot on Dell laptops. At UEFI stage the top row always works as `F` keys.